# How to launch Ubuntu From Boot loader

Tags: assembly, nasm

To sum up, I wrote a boot loader, it starts from a "floppy disk" and prints out a message, I'm using Oracle VM box to emulate a computer. Now after it prints the message I'd like to launch the installed Ubuntu... now I'm a tad confused because the one bit of information I found was to "move" my code from [ORG 0x7c00] other than that I've found nothing else online, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
mov ax, 0
mov es, ax
mov bx, 7c00h
mov cx,1
mov dx,0080h
mov ax,0204h
int 13h
jmp 0h:7c00h
```

Loads GRUB into 7c00h and jumps to it.